# Watch OS2 create local notification with custom sound

Tags: ios9, xcode7, localnotification

With a my App I'm able to create and manage a local notification in Watch. But the notification in the Watch has every time the default notification sound. Is there the possibility to define a custom sound? For example an MP3?

Comment: Did you create and schedule a notification on the watch, without routing it through the phone? If so - how'd you do that?

Comment: No, sorry probably my post is not so clear... My question is only about the possibilty ti set a different sound for the notification in the Watch